# Кастомный адаптер на основе ArrayAdapter не обновляет свои данные по notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, adapter

Для вывода во ViewStub данных с двумя полями, создал адаптер

```java
public class ProdListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MainMenuItem> {

    public ProdListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<MainMenuItem> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if(null == v) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_prod_title, null);
        }
        MainMenuItem menuItem = getItem(position);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_prod_title_imgpacman);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_prod_title_text);

        img.setImageResource(menuItem.getImageId());
        txtTitle.setText(menuItem.getTitle());

        return v;
    }

}
```

В Активити формирую данные, создаю адаптер, и назначаю адаптер.

```
        //создам список пунктов главного меню
        mProdlist = createProdList(null);

        // set adapter
        mListViewAdapter = new ProdListAdapter(this, R.layout.item_prod_title, mProdlist);
        mListViewMenu.setAdapter(mListViewAdapter);
```

На этом этапе все в порядке - список строится.

Но дальше мне нужно изменить данные по евенту. mProdlist изменяется, это видно в отладчике. А вот содержимое адаптера - нет. Соответственно, обновления вывода списка по notifyDataSetChanged() не происходит:

```
                mProdlist = createProdList(s.toString());
                mListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Где я что не так сделал? Или в коде адаптера нужно какой-то метод переопределить??

Адаптер работает с обьектами вот этого класса:

```
// структурка из картинки и наименования
public class MainMenuItem {

    private int imageId;
    private String title;

    public MainMenuItem(int imageId, String title) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }

    public void setImageId(int imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Эксперимент показал что если с данные меняются средствами Листа (.remove(item)), то Адаптер на это реагирует.

```
mListViewMenu.setAdapter(mListViewAdapter); 
mProdlist.remove(0);
```

А вот если как у меня - методом присваивания, то нет(

Comment: Нужно больше информации. Приведенный код рабочий.

Comment: Дополнил сообщение описанием класса с которым работает Адаптер.

Comment: И здесь не вижу проблем. Возможно дело в макете

Comment: Эксперимент показал что если с данные меняются средствами Листа (.remove(item)), то Адаптер на это реагирует.
```
        mListViewMenu.setAdapter(mListViewAdapter);

        mProdlist.remove(0);
```
А вот если как у меня - методом присваивания, то нет(

Comment: Попробуйте перед присвоением выполнить очистку `mProdlist.clear()`

Comment: Да. Работает. Если задействовать методы Листа, то все получается.  
    mProdlist.clear();
    mProdlist.addAll(createProdList(s.toString()));
    mListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую использовать данный метод в адаптере:

```
public void updateData(List<MainMenuItem> prodList){
    mProdlist.clear();
    mProdlist.addAll(prodList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

И в будущем обновлять данные через данный метод.